# Let $\mu(X) = \infty$. Is the collection of Borel sets on which $\mu$ is both outer and inner regular a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures

Let X be a Hausdorff topological space $X$ and $\mathcal B(X)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mu$ be a non-negative Borel measure and $B \in\mathcal B(X)$.

- $\mu$ is tight on $B$ iff
  $$\mu(B) = \sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subset B, K \text{ is compact}\}.$$
- $\mu$ is inner regular on $B$ iff
  $$\mu(B) = \sup \{\mu(C) \mid C \subset U, C \text{ is closed}\}.$$
- $\mu$ is outer regular on $B$  iff
  $$\mu(B) = \inf \{\mu(U) \mid B \subset U, U \text{ is open}\}.$$

---

It is shown in [this](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/jancol1.pdf) lecture note that

> *Theorem*: If $X$ is a metric space and $\mu$ is finite, then the collection
> $$
> \mathcal R := \{B \in\mathcal B(X) \mid \mu \text{ is inner regular and outer regular on } B\}
> $$
> is a $\sigma$-algebra.

In the proof, the author does not use any topological property of a metric space, so I think below result still holds.

> *Statement 1*: If $\mu$ is finite, then the collection
> $$
> \mathcal R := \{B \in\mathcal B(X) \mid \mu \text{ is inner regular and outer regular on } B\}
> $$
> is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I would like to ask if any of below generalizations is true.

- *Statement 2*: The collection
  $$
  \mathcal R := \{B \in\mathcal B(X) \mid \mu \text{ is inner regular and outer regular on } B\}
  $$
  is a $\sigma$-algebra.
- *Statement 3*: The collection
  $$
  \mathcal R := \{B \in\mathcal B(X) \mid \mu \text{ is inner regular on } B\}
  $$
  is a $\sigma$-algebra.
- *Statement 4*: The collection
  $$
  \mathcal R := \{B \in\mathcal B(X) \mid \mu \text{ is outer regular on } B\}
  $$
  is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Thank you so much!